# Hestia footer on blog

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im currently building a webpage for my new company, I'm using Hestia theme, in general I like how the footer looks like, but I don't like it in the blog posts. I want it to be attached to the bottom of the page. I've tried modifying the CSS, but with no result, here's how it looks now:
[footer-now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85PlE.png)

I want it to move down so it doesn't show a line of the background image. Sorry if some part of the text is not clear, I'm not a native english speaker.

Code from the footer:

```html
<div class="footer-wrapper">
                        <footer class="footer footer-black footer-big">
                        <div class="container">
                                
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><div id="text-7" class="widget widget_text">          <div class="textwidget">        <div data-elementor-type="wp-post" data-elementor-id="249" class="elementor elementor-249" data-elementor-settings="[]">
                            <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                            <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-614b301 elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="614b301" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-fd11883" data-id="fd11883" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-fcc6579 elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="fcc6579" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <a class="elementor-icon" href="https://www.instagram.com/autoimporter.es/">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fab fa-instagram"></i>         </a>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-3a99e74" data-id="3a99e74" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-0fb0b06 elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="0fb0b06" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <a class="elementor-icon" href="https://twitter.com/auto_importer">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i>            </a>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-167065a" data-id="167065a" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-8973f49 elementor-view-default elementor-widget elementor-widget-icon" data-id="8973f49" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="icon.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-icon-wrapper">
            <a class="elementor-icon" href="https://www.facebook.com/AutoImporter-707256520097820">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>           </a>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
</div>
        </div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div id="media_image-7" class="widget widget_media_image"><a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/"><img width="300" height="81" src="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/logo_invertido-300x81.png" class="image wp-image-600  attachment-medium size-medium" alt="" loading="lazy" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" srcset="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/logo_invertido-300x81.png 300w, https://autoimporter.webbing.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/logo_invertido-1024x275.png 1024w, https://autoimporter.webbing.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/logo_invertido-768x206.png 768w, https://autoimporter.webbing.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/logo_invertido-1536x412.png 1536w, https://autoimporter.webbing.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/logo_invertido-2048x550.png 2048w, https://autoimporter.webbing.online/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/logo_invertido-600x161.png 600w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px"></a></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><div id="text-8" class="widget widget_text">           <div class="textwidget">        <div data-elementor-type="wp-post" data-elementor-id="275" class="elementor elementor-275" data-elementor-settings="[]">
                            <div class="elementor-section-wrap">
                            <section class="elementor-section elementor-top-section elementor-element elementor-element-f1c05fe elementor-section-boxed elementor-section-height-default elementor-section-height-default" data-id="f1c05fe" data-element_type="section">
                        <div class="elementor-container elementor-column-gap-default">
                    <div class="elementor-column elementor-col-100 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-409d5ef" data-id="409d5ef" data-element_type="column">
            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-f838ba9 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="f838ba9" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <h3 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">Legal</h3>       </div>
                </div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-91a9805 elementor-widget-divider--view-line elementor-widget elementor-widget-divider" data-id="91a9805" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="divider.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-divider">
            <span class="elementor-divider-separator">
                        </span>
        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-4ecdee4 elementor-widget elementor-widget-text-editor" data-id="4ecdee4" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="text-editor.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                            <a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/aviso-legal/">Aviso Legal</a>
<br>
<a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/politica-de-privacidad/">Política de Privacidad</a>
<br>
<a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/politica-de-cookies/">Política de Cookies</a>                      </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                            </div>
        </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        
</div>
        </div></div>            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
                                        <div class="hestia-bottom-footer-content"><ul id="menu-menu-1" class="footer-menu pull-left"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-132"><a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/"><i class="obfx-menu-icon dashicons dashicons-admin-users"></i>Inicio</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-310"><a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/pide-tu-coche/"><i class="obfx-menu-icon fa fa-car"></i>Pide tu coche</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-55"><a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/blog/"><i class="obfx-menu-icon dashicons dashicons-welcome-write-blog"></i>Blog</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-56"><a href="https://autoimporter.webbing.online/contacto/"><i class="obfx-menu-icon dashicons dashicons-email-alt"></i>Contacto</a></li>
</ul>       </div>          </div>
                    </footer>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sticky Footer structure. This one works if the footer has limited height:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.content {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.footer {
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: -70px;
  background: #d5d5d5;
}

p {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="footer"><p>Footer</p></footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, just tried it but doesn't seem to work. Here's a link to the page so you can try to modify it with Dev Tools: https://autoimporter.webbing.online/como-trabajamos/

Thanks

Comment: If you need just to remove empty space under the footer - set `margin-bottom: 0` for `id="text-8"` widget.

Comment: Hi, I missed that, thanks!